# In SASS can I wrap a bunch of style rules in both a media query and a selector

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, mixins

I have a bunch of styles which need to apply only to the desktop version of my site. I'm using media queries to apply these styles, but to avoid the site switching to the mobile design when resizing the window I now also add a class on page load if the screen is large.

At the moment I have

```
@media (min-width: $breakpoint) {
   // my styles
}
```

How would I go about writing a mixin to achieve something like

```
@media (min-width: $breakpoint),
.not-mobile {
   // my styles
}
```

Comment: found the answer rereading the docs after posting this question http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixin-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution

```
$breakpoint: 768px;

@mixin not-mobile {
  @media (min-width: $breakpoint) {
    @content;
  }
  .not-mobile {
    @content;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should check out the [Breakpoint](https://github.com/Team-Sass/breakpoint) extension's [noqueries](https://github.com/Team-Sass/breakpoint/wiki/No-Query-Fallbacks), or [Jacket](https://github.com/Team-Sass/jacket/)'s [example media query fallback mixin](https://github.com/Team-Sass/jacket/blob/master/test/scss/style.scss#L95). These are both robust tools designed to output conditional css rules.